# Background color of header not showing up over img

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image inside my HTML div element and a header that will be overlayed on top of it. The header has a background color running the full length of the width.

[image]

But when I move the header up so it is overlayed over the pic, the background color disappears. I've tried a z-index, but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 portfolio-box">
      <img src="assets/images/pexels-photo-450597.jpeg" alt="">
      <h6 class="portfolio-title text-center text-white">Hangman</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

    </div>
  </div>                                
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-title {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Updated pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-title {
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 portfolio-box">
      <img src="http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/step1.jpg" alt="">
      <h6 class="portfolio-title text-center text-white">Hangman</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Edit 2: Added positions to the container and it works now, without the z-index.**

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. Adding a z-index on either and declaring it doesn't work.

Comment: close. But now the header hangs out of the img. See updated image in main post.

Comment: Adding relative position to the container and absolute to the header works